# Need to navigate link while clicking material ui table row in React Router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react router 4 and [React Material UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table) while clicking react material table row I can able to trigger the event by using onCellClick Event but I need to navigate another page while clicking table row.

Could you please suggest the best way to do?

```
<Table  onCellClick={()=> { alert("Table Row Clicked!! ")}} >

 <TableHeader displaySelectAll={false}
        adjustForCheckbox={false}>
        <TableRow>
          <TableHeaderColumn> First</TableHeaderColumn> 
          <TableHeaderColumn>Last</TableHeaderColumn>
        </TableRow>
 </TableHeader>
<TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false}>
        <TableRow>
          <TableRowColumn>Randal</TableRowColumn>
          <TableRowColumn>White</TableRowColumn>
        </TableRow>
 </TableBody>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution is to use the [Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) component in react-router-dom. You could "extend" the Table Row component with a Link component. Such as:

```
 <TableRow component={Link} to="/pathGoesHere">
      <TableRowColumn>Randal</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>White</TableRowColumn>
 </TableRow>
```

Another possible way is to wrap your component with the [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HoC in react-router-dom. This allows you to access the history object as a prop. This approch will allow you a bit more control and flexibility.

```
const TableView = ({ history }) => {
   return (
       <TableRow hover onClick={() => history.push("/pathGoesHere")}>
         <TableRowColumn>Randal</TableRowColumn>
         <TableRowColumn>White</TableRowColumn>
       </TableRow>
     )
}

export default withRouter(TableView)
```

Comment: First solution is preferable when you want users to be able to 'open link in new tab' by right-clicking. However, it doesn't work when using typescript. At least I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: The first solution render the table row as a tag, which is not valid HTML structure for a table...

Comment: Not good! First solution shows Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a child of <tbody>. Does anybody have better solution?